# Monitoring API with email alerts where our apps report to

Tags: email, monitoring, hosted, dashboard

We have around 5 different apps, written in c#, vb6 and asp all of which can make API calls, or webpage calls etc. They are installed on many different locations/computers.

We would like a 3rd SASS hosted system that these apps can report to once per minute, saying “yes we are still running”

We want a dashboard, showing an alive or not status, and maybe even an alert email if one app breaks/stops speaking out to your system, for more then x min.

It sounds a pretty simple system, but the ones I have looked at include far more than this.

Does anyone know of any system like this?

We run on the windows platform and asp.net webspace
(installing extra SW on all these computers is not really an option, but a call within our own sw is)

In simple terms

I want all out apps to connect to lets say

http://www.alertfakeaddy.com/reporter.php?appname=xx&location=xx&message=working

http://www.alertfakeaddy.com/reporter.php?appname=xx&location=xx&message=error-point1

http://www.alertfakeaddy.com/reporter.php?appname=xx&location=xx&message=error-point2

or use an api in  the same some of manner

once per mine

and an alerter to check these messages, for error or lack of message, and email etc, if that happens

if such a service exists, perhaps £50-70 a month would be what we are looking for

Comment: I have changed the question (title) to make it clearer. You still have not mentioned your price range.

Comment: Or operating system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB6?! Seriously?! :-)

You could use the [MQTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT) protocol, which is great for this sort of thing, and use [Node-RED](https://nodered.org/) (free) to display browser-based dashboard report.

[image]

The [SNMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) protocol is also designed for reporting the status of (networked) resources. You could search for a good GUI, there seem to be plenty.
[image]

[Nagios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagios) is pretty much industry standard for determining & reporting when network attached devices are not reachable. Perhaps you could rig something to check the port on which your app runs?

[image]

Comment: do not forget Zabbix (Free and OpenSource)

Comment: vb6 yes, being converted, all good answers

Comment: When you decide, please accept an answer; it doesn't have ot be mine :-) You can even post your own answer & accept it. Doing so will help others who read this question in future. Good luck